# How to put "+" symbol and "=" inbetween the images in latex

Tags: latex, figure

I have three images, I want to put plus symbol between two images, and then equals to. Just like below

[image: Reference image]

Image A + Image B = Image C

I am not able to produce this view in latex.

The reference code is

```
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
\centering
%\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=empty}
\subfigure[Image A]{\includegraphics[width=30mm, height=30mm {templates/image_A.png}}
\quad
 %\hspace{5mm}
\subfigure[Image B]{\includegraphics[width=30mm, height=30mm]{templates/image_B.png}}
 \hspace{2mm}
\newsubfloat{$=$}
\subfigure[Image C]{\includegraphics[width=30mm, height=30mm]{templates/Image_C.png}}
\caption{Exampleigures}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And please also tell how to remove (a),(b),(c) from the subfigures. I have seen related examples but not able to produce this.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to remove the subcaption letters is to not use subfigures, they are not necessary for your case.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ccccc}
  \includegraphics[width=30mm,valign=c]{example-image-duck}&
  +&
  \includegraphics[width=30mm,valign=c]{example-image-duck}&
  =&
  \includegraphics[width=30mm,valign=c]{example-image-duck}\\[6ex]
  Image A && Image B && Image C\\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Multi-focus image fusion}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]